# How can I refresh the log list in the Developer Console?

Tags: developer-console

My latest debug log always seems missing in the Logs browser when I am working in the Developers Console. Is there a way to force the list of logs to refresh?

The only workaround that seems to work for me is if I can find an old entry in the log list and try to open that. The open then fails and the Log list is updated with my latest logs at the bottom of the list.

Is there a more sane way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has been a little while since you used it, it stops updating the list with new logs. You can click on "Resume updating" which appears in the top list of buttons just to the right of where you can enter anonymous apex. (The button only appears when it has stopped updating the log list)

Answer (score 0):

I do it so:

- click on the "Clear" button before processing any actions
- Executing some dummy code in the dev console, like `System.debug('blah');`

This will normally "wake up" the console.